# How can i remove commit history in Github Desktop?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I have encountered such a problem.

[image]

I only have experience with Github Destop.

How can i remove commit history in **Github Desktop** ?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, I find an **Undo** button under the commit button.

The problem is solved. It is ok now.